# How to copy a DVD

Tags: dvd, clipboard

I was offered a couple of DVDs from abroad that cannot be played on my player due to region filtering.

So I tried `k9copy` to copy the DVD (it removes the region automatically).
But for some reasons the copy does not work well (followed the instructions [from here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/K9Copy) but the generated ISO file does not work / not even in media player - additionally there are many bugs in k9copy 2.3.5 (latest from Ubuntu) showing that it is not a reliable software, at least not on Gnome...).

My question is simple: how to copy a DVD on Ubuntu, the copy/ISO being as close to the original, but without the region code.

Comment: Legally speaking the terms and conditions of this site bind us to US law and as such, the finer points of the DMCA. Technically speaking I believe this stops us facilitating the removal of DRM, which region locking is. Helping you here would violate the terms of the site. Sorry.

Comment: @Oli Ok. Well I wanted to find a solution on Ubuntu, as there are some working tools on Windows, and on the Mac.

Comment: I understand your desire to find a solution for this issue. However, this needs to be closed due largely in part to @Oli's comments. Best of luck uncovering a solution!

Comment: There are solutions, plenty of them, we're just not allowed to help people remove DRM here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most user-friendly method in my opinion is just right-click on the DVD icon on your desktop and select "Copy disc" (I'm not sure about the name of the menu item). This uses the package *libdvdcss2* and the software Brasero, which is shipped with Ubuntu.

Reference: [Ubuntu Wiki: ripping dvds](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/RippingDVDs)

Comment: Unfortunately the region code is copied as well.